# searching text files

Tags: iphone

I’m desperately searching for some simple app that searches for text strings in a specified directory of about 1000 text files. Does anyone know if such a thing exists, or has anyone ever programmed such an app?

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: Are you looking for example code for an iOS implementation, or a tool to help you with your software development?

Comment: example code, i want to do it by coding....

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the searching within an `NSOperation` subclass. It would use file descriptors instead of `NSString`s to keep memory usage down. To perform the actual search I would implement an algorithm that doesn't require the input to be indexed, such as the [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm). See [Efficient way to search a stream for a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846175/efficient-way-to-search-a-stream-for-a-string) for more details.